# How can I use Ransack gem to search a date and another value types in multiple columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

In my view I wanna search a value in a date column  and a string column with the same text_field using Ransack gem.

I've already known how to search multiple strings columns with just one text field, but searching a date column and a string column has been proving to be hard.

I tried something like this in the view:

```
<%= f.search_field :date_or_name_eq, { :class => "form-control", :placeholder => "Search..." } %>
```

And this in the controller:

```
@q = MyModel.ransack(params[:q])
@q.sorts = 'created_at desc' if @q.sorts.empty?
@my_model = @q.result().order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page]).per(20).distinct
```

But that, doesn't work. It ignores the name column for searching. It only brings what it find in the date column. And I need something that work for search in theese two columns.

Can someone help me?

For pagination I use the Kaminari gem.

Answer (score 2):

This is absolutely possible with Ransack. Perhaps your date input cannot be parsed (`Time.zone.parse` is used internally) or that parsed time doesn't actually match anything.

I tried this on my app, where I also use Ransack:

Ruby code:

```
Client.ransack(name_or_updated_at_eq: '1. Januar 2011').result()
```

Generated SQL:

```
SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE 
    ("clients"."name" = '1. Januar 2011' OR "clients"."updated_at" = '2011-01-01 00:00:00')
```

(Note that Rails has no problem parsing the localized date)

The resulting `Time` instance contains also a time which is missing from the original query input. If the database column doesn't match the same time *exactly* Ransack returns no match. (With a pure date column this should work, though)

If that is actually the cause, you can use a custom *ransacker*:

In `MyModel` add:

```
ransacker :my_date_column, type: :date do
  Arel.sql('date(my_date_column)')
end
```

Depending on your database backend you might need a different syntax to cast the timestamp into a date. (e.g. try `date_trunc('day', my_date_column)` for PostgreSQL)

More details on Ransackers: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/using-ransackers

Comment: If anyone gets PG::AmbiguousColumn - ERROR:  column reference "<column_name>" is ambiguous, use Arel.sql('date(<table_name>.<column_name>)')